# Объясните смысл новшеств C# 7

Tags: c#

В новой версии превью Visual Studio "15" появилась вот такая конструкция, которая возвращает ссылку на объект:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] numbers = { 0b1, 0b10, 0b100, 0b1000, 0b1_000, 0b10_0000 };
    ref int r = ref Find(numbers, x => x > 4);
    WriteLine($"{r} == {numbers[4]}");
    r = 0;
    WriteLine($"{r} == {numbers[4]}");
}

static ref Find(int[] list, Func<int, bool> pred)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; !pred(list[i]); i++) ;
    return ref list[i];
}
```

В чем смысл этого нововведения? Разве если мы возвращаем объект из метода, то мы его не возвращаем неявно ссылку на него?

Так же появились локальные функции. В чем их юзабельность, разве без них обойтись нельзя? На мой взгляд это понизит качество кода, так как со стороны функция будет похожа на класс с методами.

```
class Program
{
    int[] numbers = { 0b1, 0b10, 0b100, 0b1000, 0b1_0000, 0b10_0000 };

    (int, int) Tally(IEnumerable<int> list)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, оформите код текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: второе это же замыкания. А вот первое возвращаеться объект если делать просто `return` т.е. если взглянуть на php то `$object1 = find()` и объект `$object2 = find()` это разные объекты. а если возвращать просто ссылку это один и тот же объект. Подход хорош для реализации так называемого патерна регистри, при котором `object1` будет равен `object2`.

Comment: Обе фичи с не слишком широкой областью применимости. 1. Возможность использования результата функции как lvalue. Например, `Max(ref a, ref b, ref c) = 10;` - выбор максимального из аргументов и присвоение ему значения. Если возвращаем структуру - не понадобится создавать ее копию. 2. Одноразовые хэлпер-методы (выглядит почти как лямбда, только без выделения памяти под делегат). Интересно, можно ли использовать замыкания.

Comment: @kmv: Да, можно.

Comment: @VladD Ага, посмотрел. Без замыкания, как и ожидалось, создается статический метод, с замыканием - есть отличие от лямбды. Вместо класса с полем создается статический метод, в которую передается аргументом автогенерированная структура с полями под замкнутые переменные. Ну и делегаты не создаются.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, это preview не Visual Studio 2015 (она уже вышла), а следующего релиза, номер версии которого как раз 15. (У VS 2015 номер версии 14.)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

По первой части, это интересно для типов-значений.

С ссылочными типами нет особой разницы, работаете вы с объектом по оригиналу ссылки или по её копии. Но с типами-значениями, такими как `int`, вы получаете копию значения. Для возвращаемого `ref` вы можете работать таки с оригиналом.

Таким образом, вы уменьшаете объём копирования структур (которое может быть проблемой в высокопроизводительном коде).

Кроме того, вы сможете писать код наподобие «найти точку с наибольшим `X` и увеличить у неё `Y`», потому что судя по всему станут возможны функции наподобие

```
ref Point MaxBy(Point[] points, Func<Point, double> selector)
{
    ref Point result = ref points[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < points.Length; i++)
        if (selector(result) < selector(point[i]))
            result = ref point[i];
    return result;
}

ref Point rightmost = MaxBy(points, p => p.X);
rightmost.Y += 1;
```

---

По поводу локальных функций, мне кажется, часто, наоборот, приватные функции классов используются как костыль на отсутствие локальных функций. Часто в приватную функцию выносится хелпер из одной функции, не имеющий значения внутри класса. Локальная функция — более правильный путь для таких функций.

Дополнительно, локальные функции «видят» локальные переменные в охватывающей функции, а значит, вам не придётся передавать в них кучу вспомогательных аргументов.

---

Ещё один юзкейс для локальных функций — итераторы и async-функции. Смотрите. Если у вас есть код

```
IEnumerable<int> GetOdd(IEnumerable<int> s)
{
    if (s == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    foreach (var v in s)
        if (v % 2 != 0)
            yield return v;
}
```

— то проверка будет выполнена, и исключение брошено лишь после начала перечисления. То есть код

```
IEnumerable<int> odds;
try
{
    odds = GetOdd(seq);
}
catch (ArgumentException)
{
    return false;
}
foreach (var v in odds)
    Console.WriteLine(v);
```

не поймает исключение. То есть, пользователю придётся знать, будет ли исключение брошено во время вызова или во время перечисления.

С локальными функциями вы можете написать так:

```
IEnumerable<int> GetOdd(IEnumerable<int> s)
{
    if (s == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    // обратите внимание, `Inner` без параметров
    IEnumerable<int> Inner()
    {
        foreach (var v in s)
            if (v % 2 != 0)
                yield return v;
    }
    return Inner();
}
```

Исключение будет при этом брошено сразу, при вызове `GetOdd`, а не при перечислении. Очевидно, что внутренняя функция имеет смысл лишь для `GetOdd`, так что не стоит заводить для неё отдельную функцию на внешнем уровне, пусть даже и приватную.

Comment: ну наконец-то, поддержка локальных функций таки случилась. Костыль со вспомогательными внешними функциями корнями растет еще из Фортрана, если память не изменяет, а может и глубже. Потом этот принцип перетащили в Си, а оттуда, вместе с синтаксисом, и в другие языки.

Comment: @rdorn, а вот в gcc (диалект Си) вложенные функции добавили уже давно.

Comment: @avp ну так то диалект... в стандарте то до сих пор нет, или я что-то упустил?

Comment: @rdorn, наверное нет (я их не изучаю, похоже как и Вы). Но, (imho) для пишущих в linux это не важно, поскольку gcc там всегда есть.

Comment: Знаю, что вопросу сто лет в обед, но я тут вчера тестировал скорость работы локальной функции и аналогичной ей приватной. Результаты весьма интересны: локальная (вне зависимости от сложности вычислений) отрабатывает быстрее аналогичной приватной на 11-12%. В том случае, если приватной был проставлен AggressiveInlining, то выигрыш уменьшается до 8-9%. Но данные величины все равно являются весомыми. А по сему - использование локальных функций вместо малозначимых относительно общей структуры приватных не просто приветствуется, а я бы даже сказал - обязательно

Comment: @Kir_Antipov: Интересно! А можете где-нибудь выложить результаты сравнения?

Comment: @VladD Конечно, сейчас создам под это дело тему

Answer (score 7):

Я не претендую на полную правдивость, но с логической точки зрения все так:

Если мы уберем `ref`, то в первом сниппете мы вернем не элемент списка, а его свежесозданную копию. Т.е. если мы ее (копию) модифицируем, то в оригинальном списке изменение не отразится. Это не совсем то поведение, которое ожидается от ф-ции.

Comment: Но, ведь, это верно лишь в случае с использованием "структурных" типов данных. [Если я не ошибаюсь в терминологии] То есть когда есть набор конкретных значений которые передаются буквально как копия. Но вот если мы рабоатем с каким-то обьектом класса -- тогда разници вообще нету. Ибо и так передается референс на обьект. Независимо от того есть ref или нет. (примеры: list, array, обьекты своих кастомных классов.)

Comment: Нет, это контринтуитивно. Должен быть явный способ передавать объект по ссылке. Без создания копии.

Comment: Контринтуитивность -- это уже вопрос правильной стилистики написания кода(!) а не ответ на заданный вопрос :) Не подменяй понятия.