# Для чего действительно нужны локальные функции?

Tags: c#

Вот в этом [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/539509/179270) поднимается вопрос о планируемых нововведения в [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) версии 7.

В частности меня заинтересовали так называемые *локальные функции*.

В [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539516/179270) @VladD есть пример как может быть использована *локальная функция*:

```
IEnumerable<int> GetOdd(IEnumerable<int> s)
{
    if (s == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    // обратите внимание, `Inner` без параметров
    IEnumerable<int> Inner()
    {
        foreach (var v in s)
            if (v % 2 != 0)
                yield return v;
    }
    return Inner();
}
```

но мне кажется данный пример слегка *натянутым*, в данном случае можно было бы наверно и обойтись без функции `Inner()`.

Так же мне непонятно следующее высказывание:

> По поводу локальных функций, мне кажется, часто, наоборот, приватные функции классов используются как костыль на отсутствие локальных функций. Часто в приватную функцию выносится хелпер из одной функции, не имеющий значения внутри класса. Локальная функция — более правильный путь для таких функций.

У себя в коде я оформляю отдельными методами код на основании следующих правил:

1. Функционал который может быть повторно использован;
2. Вынесения функционала в отдельный метод что бы поддерживать *стройность* функции;
3. Прочее

---

Например:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetPhonesForNotice(requestId)
{
    var requestState = GetStateOfRequest(int requestId);
    switch(requestState)
    {
        case "Открыта":
        {
            return getRecipientsForNewRequest(int requestId);
            break;
        }
        case "Закрыта":
        {
            return getRecipientsForClosedRequest(int requestId);
            break;
        }
    }
}

private IEnumerable<string> getRecipientsForNewRequest(int requestId)
{
}
private IEnumerable<string> getRecipientsForClosedRequest(int requestId)
{
}
```

Если я правильно понял то тогда в новой версии языка функции ***getRecipientsForNewRequest(int requestId)***, ***getRecipientsForClosedRequest(int requestId)*** можно будет реализовать внутри *главной* функции ***GetPhonesForNotice(int requestId)*** но я не понимаю чем это правильней/лучше текущего варианта?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Мне кажется вот как.

Вопрос не в технической стороне дела. (Хотя технические отличия есть, они приведены в конце ответа.) С технической стороны, можно организовать такую же приватную функцию, в которую передавать все параметры явно. А если внутренняя функция должна иметь меньше параметров (например, из-за того, что требуется специфическая сигнатура), можно построить closure. Все технические вопросы решаемы и в рамках старых возможностей. (Точно так же как можно было бы обойтись без свойств и использовать пару функций, без классов, и передавать `this` в методы явно и т. д.)

Дело в том, что мы хотим не загрязнять хелпер-функциями класс, а положить их внутри того, к чему они относятся. Это полная аналогия идеи о том, что класс должен содержать всё то, что необходимо ему для работы, и не требовать «внешнего» управления. Точно так же и тут, функция содержит *внутри себя* то, что нужно для работы, а приватные вспомогательные *методы* получаются необходимы лишь там, где они не ограничены смыслом одной функции — то есть, там, где они осмысленны в рамках *всего класса*.

С таким подходом, да, локальные переменные некоторым образом заменяют поля класса, так что в ситуациях, когда раньше вам нужно было создавать внутренний класс и вызывать в нём методы, теперь можно сделать то же самое удобнее с локальными функциями.

Кроме того, уменьшение обвязочного кода наподобие неявной передачи переменных всегда важно, так обвязочный код — возможность ошибиться.

---

В качестве ещё одного мотивирующего примера:

```
void SortBy<T>(List<T> list, Func<List, double> expr, bool ascending)
{
    int comparerAscending(T t1, T t2)
    {
        return expr(t1).Compare(expr(t2));
    }

    int comparerDescending(T t1, T t2)
    {
        return expr(t2).Compare(expr(t1));
    }

    list.Sort(ascending ? comparerAscending : comparerDescending);
}
```

Без локальных функций вам пришлось бы создавать внутренние делегаты.

---

Ещё один сценарий, в котором внутренние функции могут быть полезны — кодогенерация. Если вы генерируете вспомогательную функцию, вы можете случайно попасть на уже занятое имя, вы ведь не знаете, что там в остальной части класса. Если вспомогательная функция «упакована» в другую функцию, этой проблемы не возникает.

---

**Дополнение:** Давайте рассмотрим, кроме логических, отличия между локальными функциями и уже существующими средствами языка.

Отличие от приватной нелокальной функции состоит, кроме «скрытого» имени, в том, что локальная функция «видит» переменные, объявленные в охватывающей функции до неё. Таким образом, отпадает необходимость передавать параметры в локальную функцию *явно*, и значит, мы можем более свободно управлять её сигнатурой. (Это может быть важно, см. пример с `SortBy`.)

Отличие локальной функции от аналогичного локально объявленного делегата с лямбда-функцией состоит в том, что

- делегатная переменная может быть переопределена, имя локальной функции не может быть перепривязано
- лямбда-функции требуют хитрого синтаксиса для реализации рекурсивного вызова, который таки ломается при последующем изменении делегатной переменной (Y-комбинатор не предлагать!), у локальных функций проблем не возникает
- лямбда-функция не может быть генератором (`yield return`)
- вы не можете объявить обобщённую лямбда функцию (`Func<T, int> f = t => 1;` не скомпилируется для неизвестного типа `T`), с локальными функциями проблем не возникает
- производительность: делегат означает лишнюю аллокацию экземпляра делегатного типа; локальная функция этого недостатка лишена, и дополнительная аллокация нужна лишь для случая нетривиального замыкания.

Литература: [C# Design Notes for May 20, 2015](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/3911)

Comment: чем в примере с `Sort` локальные функции будут отличаться от внутренних делегатов?

Comment: @Grundy: Ну, во-первых, по сути это вложенные функции, а делегат в данной точке — лишь костыль на отсутствие их в языке. Во-вторых, делегат можно переназначить, с делегатом нужны танцы с бубном для рекурсии, делегат не может содержать `yield return`. Ну и делегат — это класс-обёртка над функцией, он менее эффективен.

Comment: Думаю стоит это добавить в ответ, а то сейчас вообще никакой разницы не видно, с делегатами даже компактнее выглядело б, как-то так `list.Sort(ascending ? (a,b)=>a.Compare(b) : (a,b)=>b.Compare(a));`, с рекурсией тоже проблем нет - даешь имя делегату и вполне можешь его использовать, а с остальным да и плюс `ref`/`out` параметры

Comment: @Grundy: Написал. С рекурсией проблемы есть, потому что делегатная переменная может быть переназначена. Пример: `Func<int, int> f = null; f = (n => n == 0 ? 0 : 1 + f(n - 1)); var g = f; if (negative) f = (n => n == 0 ? 0 : -1 + f(n + 1)); g(1);`

Comment: Не захотел писать отдельный вопрос. Не понимаю про аллокацию. Многие пишут, что ламбды требуют аллокацию, но судя по этому http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742278/c-sharp-lambda-allocation-and-collection ее нет. Также в тестовом коде где в цикле триллион раз создается и используется ламбда (GC выключен) не наблюдается никакого роста потребления памяти и количество объектов в снапшотах не меняется. Кто ошибается?

Comment: @vitidev: По идее, лямбда, не «замыкающаяся» ни по каким переменным, _может_ быть скомпилирована в статический метод. Лямбда, «замыкающаяся» только по полям/свойствам, может быть скомпилирована в нестатический метод. Остальные лямбды по идее компилируются в отдельный объект. Аллокации делегата не избежать, но он _может_ быть закеширован, если оптимизатор решит, что это безопасно. Так что давайте етстовый код, посмотрим, что генерируется. (Наверное, лучше не здесь, а в [чате по C#](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26962/c-net--).)

Answer (score 3):

Для себя нашел пользу в случае когда: 
Допустим в методе `GetPhonesForNotice` есть локальная переменная `name`, и эта же переменная будет/должна находится в методах `getRecipientsForNewRequest`, `getRecipientsForClosedRequest`.

```
public Class PhoneBook
{ 
    public IEnumerable<string> GetPhonesForNotice(requestId)
    {
        string name="qqq"; //локальная переменная
        var requestState = GetStateOfRequest(int requestId);
        switch(requestState)
        {
           case "Открыта":
           {
                return getRecipientsForNewRequest(int requestId);
                break;
           }
           case "Закрыта":
           {
               return getRecipientsForClosedRequest(int requestId);
               break;
           }
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> getRecipientsForNewRequest(int requestId)
    {
         //какие-то операции с name
    } 
    private IEnumerable<string> getRecipientsForClosedRequest(int requestId)
    {
         //какие-то операции с name
    }
}
```

В таком случае переменную `name` придется выносить за пределы метода `GetPhonesForNotice`:

```
public Class PhoneBook
{ 
    private name = "qqq"; //вынесли локальную переменную из метода

    public IEnumerable<string> GetPhonesForNotice(requestId)
    {           
        var requestState = GetStateOfRequest(int requestId);
        //какие-то операции с name
        switch(requestState)
        {
           case "Открыта":
           {
                return getRecipientsForNewRequest(int requestId);
                break;
           }
           case "Закрыта":
           {
               return getRecipientsForClosedRequest(int requestId);
               break;
           }
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> getRecipientsForNewRequest(int requestId)
    {
         //какие-то операции с name
    } 
    private IEnumerable<string> getRecipientsForClosedRequest(int requestId)
    {
         //какие-то операции с name
    }
}
```

либо передавать ее в качестве параметра методам `getRecipientsForNewRequest`, `getRecipientsForClosedRequest`. С использованием локальных функций не пришлось бы делать ни того, ни другого.

Как вывод, польза локальных функций - не приходится плодить приватные переменные для нескольких методов и не засорять входными параметрами приватные методы.

Comment: да согласен про переменные, в случае если бы я использовал локальные то тогда `getRecipientsForNewRequest()` &  `getRecipientsForClosedRequest()` бы были без параметров, просто в этом случае может сильно разрастись *главная* функция

Comment: @Bald, полагаю, что при сильном разрастании основного метода из-за локальных функций многие всё же сделают отдельный класс, либо какой-нибудь решарпер будет предлагать это сделать за нас, т.к. несмотря на некоторые удобства, всё равно большое количество локальных монстров и бизнес логика меж/под/над ними не есть гуд