# Когда наиболее правильно использовать вложенные функции?

Tags: c#, .net

В c# 7.0 появились вложенные функции. Собственно вопрос, а когда использование данного синтаксиса оправданно? Я понимаю, что это синтаксический сахар, но ИМХО и без них раньше жилось хорошо. Подчеркнуть, что данная функция вызывается в одном месте? Ну не знаю...

Comment: Никто не запрещает плодить приватные функции, которые нужны в одном месте и потом путаться в них. Фломастеры это все.

Comment: @vitidev, ну не знаю. По мне так и во вложенных функциях путаться можно. Тем более вложенность может быть любой. Еще я заметил, то ли баг, то ли фича, что нельзя в локальной функции в дебаггере посмотреть переменную из внешний функции, которая передавалась не в виде параметра.

Comment: Или даже лучше вот этот: [Для чего действительно нужны локальные функции?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/540355/186999)

Comment: Теперь вы можете в код-гольфе написать типа `void w<T>(T t)=>Console.Write(t);` и если вывод в консоль используется хотя бы в нескольких местах - выиграть пару символов: `w("Hello");` )))

Comment: Это очередное, что в C# тянут из функционального подхода, так что если вам интересные "новые" возможности C#, то я просто советую вам познакомиться с F# где все это было реализовано намного раньше и во многом лучше.

Comment: Если вы все-таки заинтересуетесь F#, то заходите в [F#-чат комнату](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f) - не стесняйтесь спрашивать если будут вопросы, в любом случае буду рад вас видеть.

Comment: @FoggyFinder: А ещё раньше это было реализовано в насквозь процедурном Паскале.

Answer (score 3):

> Подчеркнуть, что данная функция вызывается в одном месте?

Не обязательно. Она может выполняться и много раз в методе, в котором она вложена. Просто сейчас такие "локально выполняемые" функции можно не выносить в класс. Как следствие - класс будет чище и читабельней.

К слову, вложенная функция имеет доступ к локальным переменным метода:

```
var number = 23;
void DoAction()
{
    Console.WriteLine(number); // 23
}

DoAction();
```

Так же нашел пользу использования вложенных функций в подписках на события.
Давайте приведу пример, как это выглядело раньше:

```
EventHandler createdEventHandler = null;
createdEventHandler += (sender, e) =>
{
    something.Created -= createdEventHandler;
    ...
};
something.Created += createdEventHandler;
```

А теперь с помощью вложенных функций:

```
void OnCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    something.Created -= OnCreated;
    ...
}
something.Created += OnCreated;
```

Что выглядит читабельней?

---

Нашел еще красивый пример, [размещенный VladD'ом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/540423/235242):

```
void SortBy<T>(List<T> list, Func<List, double> expr, bool ascending)
{
    int comparerAscending(T t1, T t2)
    {
        return expr(t1).Compare(expr(t2));
    }

    int comparerDescending(T t1, T t2)
    {
        return expr(t2).Compare(expr(t1));
    }

    list.Sort(ascending ? comparerAscending : comparerDescending);
}
```

Comment: А у вас локальные переменные из внешней функции отображаются в дебаггере, когда вы заходите в локальную? У меня почему-то ругается на контекст.

Comment: Пример с событиями как-то натянуто выглядит, особенно если убрать инициализацию с помощью null

Comment: @Grundy а вы не сможете избавиться от инициализации с помощью null, когда вам надо будет отписываться от этого события при его срабатывании (переменная еще не создана).